# is it possible to separate var styles = StyleSheet.create from React.component into different script in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

is it possible to separate var styles = StyleSheet.create from React.component into different script in react native?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

that's possible. just create a js file with this pattern:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');

var myStyles = React.StyleSheet.create({
   style1: { },
   style2: { }
)}

module.exports = myStyles;
```

then in your component js use require to use that style sheet e.g. assuming your style js file is named phongyewtong.js

```
var s = require('../the/path/to/phongyewtong');
```

usage:

```
<View style = {s.style1} />
```

Answer (score 7):

Both of the below links explain very well how to move styles out of your 'structural' code :

1. https://hackernoon.com/manage-react-native-project-folder-structure-and-simplify-the-code-c98da77ef792
2. https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/tips-for-styling-your-react-native-apps-3f61608655eb

Basically (copying code snippet from above link #2) have your styles in separate JS, say text.js file :

```
const text = StyleSheet.create({
    p: {
      color: 'black',
      fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
      fontSize: 14,
    },
    title: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      color: 'black',
      fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
      fontSize: 20,
    }
  });

export default text;
```

In React component, you can simply import this text style, and use it directly

```
<Text style={text.p}>settings</Text>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In a more recent React Version (0.31) I used this code:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ...
});

module.exports = styles;
```

Comment: and how do you import it?

Comment: It can be imported as (assuming name of the file is style.js) - import styles from './style';